# Portable class doesn't work Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am tryng to create/open a xamarin forms project (portable)...But I always see this message and the pcl is not created, only android and ios is created...
I am using Visual Studio 2017
And I've just installed xamarin in this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you look at the log file like the error message suggests?

Comment: Where Do I found that?

Comment: In your first screenshot it says the path to the _Log.xml_ file. Path starting with _C:/Users/user/AppData_...... look in your screenshot